# Write an Oracle query that has changing constants

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to write an Oracle query that will fill in missing fields from a set of data not in a database.

That is, I will have the data

```
+----+-----+-----+
|Name|Name2|Name3|
+----+-----+-----+
|A   |1    |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|B   |1    |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|C   |2    |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|Z   |39   |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|... |...  |...  |
+----+-----+-----+
|... |...  |...  |
+----+-----+-----+
|... |...  |...  |
+----+-----+-----+
|QF  |893  |     |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Name is unique, and not in a database.

Name2 is not unique, and exists both inside and outside the database.

Name3 is unknown and desired, not unique, is defined by Name2 (the mapping between Name2 and Name3 is one-to-one), and is in the database.

A single query in sql could be modeled like this,

```
SELECT MY_TABLE.Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE.Name2='1'
```

And I would know to place whatever that query returns into the first two rows of my data.

Then I could repeat it for the remaining rows

```
SELECT MY_TABLE.Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE.Name2='2'
```

Though this would require I write and run thousands of individual select statements, and copy what the statement returns however many times Name2 repeats.

Is there a way to write a single select statement to fill in my missing columns, keeping in mind that the column Name is not in a database, and the time it takes to write the query is of no concern?

An ideal query would be something like this,

```
SELECT Name, MY_TABLE.Name2, MY_TABLE.Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 
   (MAGICALLY_SET Name = 'A' AND
    Name2 = '1') OR
   (MAGICALLY_SET Name = 'B' AND
    Name2 = '1') OR
   (MAGICALLY_SET Name = 'C' AND
    Name2 = '2')
   ...
   (MAGICALLY_SET Name = 'QF' AND
    Name2 = '893');
```

Which would return the data already nicely set.

```
+----+-----+-----------------+
|Name|Name2|Name3            |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|A   |1    |returned_value1  |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|B   |1    |returned_value1  |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|C   |2    |returned_value54 |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|Z   |39   |returned_value87 |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|... |...  |...              |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|... |...  |...              |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|... |...  |...              |
+----+-----+-----------------+
|QF  |893  |returned_value439|
+----+-----+-----------------+
```

I've attempted writing select statements that change a constant Name value, and using dual, but I don't believe I'm on the right track.

If Name was in a table, I know I could write a query for that. But there is no ability to make a new table, and insert all the Name/Name2 data.

Any ideas?

Comment: from where do you retrieve the data of the `Name` column? Also, how would you decide which `Name` goes with which `Name2`?

Comment: what about loading all the csv into a table first? oracle has a very convenient loader for this. It is a single line.

Comment: My access to the table/database is read only.

Comment: how many different values for `Name`?

Comment: 55,621. The query can easily be generated from the csv file, thus why 'writing' the query is of no concern. Simply the running, and compilation of final data is my problem.

Comment: Also, how would you decide which `Name` goes with which `Name2`?Is it also in the csv?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to be a bit more clear. Name exists outside of the database. Name2 exists both inside and outside of the database. Name3 exists inside the datbase.

Comment: Changing contstants?  Are they anything like variables?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a less than ideal solution,

```
SELECT 'A' AS Name, Name2, Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME2 = '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS Name, Name2, Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME2 = '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' AS Name, Name2, Name3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME2 = '2' UNION ALL
...
```

Which could be wrapped in a single select * from, But it did output correctly,

```
Name, Name2, Name3
A     1      returned_value1
B     1      returned_value1
C     2      returned_value54
...
```